# How to forecast values more accurate with Python and polynomial regression?

Tags: python, plot, predict, forecast

I am building a forecast application using polynomial regression. However, the values predicted aren't that close to the actual values, as can be seen in the photo attached. How can I modify the algorithm, so that the prediction can be more accurate? Also, I have seen that polynomial spline tries to go through every point of data . Can I train my algorithm to predict the next values using also spline? My data is 70% train data and 30% test data. The code: https://github.com/iulianastroia/work/blob/master/predict_algorithms_november/polynomial_regression_MEAN_DATA_NOVEMBER.py

The Plot:
[image]

Comment: remove the trend and stationarity the do this. You need to transform the data if there is trend and seasonality

Comment: You need to calculate and pay attention to the $r^2$ value to quantify how well the regression represents the data.

Comment: @Pygirl how can I remove that?

Comment: @DavidCollins I have already calculated that. It is  0.12480706728214275. I have seen that anywhere between 0 and 1 is considered to be normal. Is it alright?

Comment: No, 'normal' is not a descriptor of r^2.  Near 1 is a very strong correlation.  Near 0 is very weak.  `0.12` means the polynomial regression does a poor job of representing the data.

Comment: @DavidCollins and what can I do to improve it then?